# Punctuation with the word "also"

Tags: punctuation

When using the word "also" in a sentence, what punctuation is needed?

Example:
"Changing to diet sodas and other low calorie drink choices also have students thinking twice about beverage choices."

Comment: It's an interesting and unobvious grammatical question.  Did any of the five close voters listed above think about it at all?  Do any of them know any grammar?  This kind of thoughtless close-voting happens too often!

Comment: Unrelated to question: In this sentence, "have" should be "has" because that verb refers to "changing". You wouldn't say "Changing has students thinking twice"; it'd be "Changing has students thinking twice", so the details of what is changing shouldn't be where we look to determine whether the verb should be plural or singular.

Comment: @GregLee I always like your answer and am a fan of it. I am sorry that it was considered as a thoughtless close-voting. I am just following the rules. The question reads more like a proof-reading request than a question related with grammar or comma rules. The OP should have posted it with his/her own research where he was confused with its usage. He has a chance to edit the question to make it more *on-topic* and I don't think close-voting kills the question. That's why it is put ***on hold***.

Answer (score 1):

If "also" modifies the following verb phrase, there's no comma:

> "[Changing to diet sodas and other low calorie drink choices] [also has students thinking twice about beverage choices]."

This means that there are various effects that changing to diet sodas has, and in addition to these effects, it also has students thinking twice.

But if "also" modifies the preceding subject, there's a comma:

> "[Changing to diet sodas and other low calorie drink choices also,] [has students thinking twice about beverage choices]."

This means that there are various factors that make students think twice, but in addition to these, changing to diet sodas also makes students think twice.

There is also an interpretation where "also" modifies "and other low calorie drink choices", and a comma is needed there, also:

> "[Changing to diet sodas [and other low calorie drink choices also,]] [has students thinking twice about beverage choices]."

Answer (score 0):

*Also* is an adverb here; it modifies or gives more information about the word "changing".

Because of the construction of your sentence, there's no further punctuation needed here for *also*.

Just like with other adverbs, you'd need a comma after it if you were using it to begin a sentence:

> "Also, he ate twelve bananas."
>
> *(Here's what it looks like with another random adverb: "Apparently, he ate twelve bananas.")*

Or if you were using it as a parenthetical, a comma both before and after:

> "To be precise, it was twelve bananas, two entire grapefruits, five and a half peaches and, also, one of those mini watermelons."
>
> *("It was twelve bananas, two grapefruits, five and a half peaches and, apparently, one of those mini watermelons.")*

But the second example is a little strange and probably is not common.